# What is the difference between "Smooth scrolling" in JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello I can't understand what the difference between this:
CSS

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


</style>
```

And this:

https://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/FCpBo

Why we should use JS - Smooth scrolling if I can write this in a line of CSS code????

Comment: The CSS feature is relatively new, and user agents (browsers) are allowed to ignore it if they want to. It is not supported by IE 11.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior) not in all browser work `scroll-behavior`

Comment: Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior